# Add Google Analytics to Android project - Error: Unable to load class 'com.google.gson.JsonObject'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-analytics, android-gradle-plugin

I followed this link to add Analytics to my project:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

This is my project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}
```

and this is my module build.gradle (I put the plugin at the bottom of the file):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'org.quanqi:android-view-pager-indicator:0.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I followed the link step by step but I got this error:
[image]

(I'm using gralde plugin v 2.10)

What is wrong?!!!

Comment: Did you add GSON library? I don't see it in your dependencies.

Comment: I fount the solution.I had to update Android Support Repository & Google Play Services & Google Repository to the last version (Where google guys didn't mentioned in the documentation!!!)